# Powershell "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: sql-server, database, excel, powershell, oledb

i am running a powershell program to insert the data from Excel to database:

```
param([int]$StepNumber=1)


$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path

$datestr=$(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$url="http://www.dtcc.com/~/media/Files/Downloads/client-center/NSCC/NSCC-MPID-Directory.xls"
$destination = $directorypath +"/NSCC-MPID-Directory"+"_"+$datestr+".xls"

## if destination does not exsist, creat a new one.
if (!(Test-Path $destination) ) {
    New-Item $destination  -type file -force
}

$client = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
$client.DownloadFile( $url, $destination)





$filepath = $destination
$excelConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$filepath;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
$sqlConnection = 'Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SIAC;Data Source=database1;'
$excelQuery = 'select * from [OTC$]'
$tablename = 'NSCC_MPID_OTC'

Try {
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($excelConnection)
    $conn.open()
    $cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()
    $cmd.CommandText = $excelQuery
    $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
    $sqlbc = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($sqlConnection, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock)
    $sqlbc.DestinationTableName = $tableName
    #$sqlbc.Batchsize = 1000
    #$sqlbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 60
    #$sqlbc.EnableStreaming=$true

    # add all  columns - you can  add as few  as you like.
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $rdr.FieldCount; $i++) {
        $fname = $rdr.GetName($i)
        Write-Host $fname -ForegroundColor green
        [void]$sqlbc.ColumnMappings.Add($fname, $fname)
    }

    # write all of the data to the table
    Try {
        $sqlbc.WriteToServer($rdr)
    } Catch {
        Write-Host "$_" -Fore red -back white
    } Finally {
        $rdr.Close()    
    }
} Catch {
    Write-Host "$_" -ForegroundColor red
}
```

When I run the program which needs to use the OLE DB Provider, it gives the error: "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provider is not registered on the local machine. Can someone tell me why it can not find the provider when it is already there.

I tried dowloading Microsoft Database Access Engine 2017 and  Microsoft Database Access Engine 2010 Redistributible and still have the same error.  I also restart my computer and try run as administrator.... No thing worked for me.

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: The answer is to install the Access redis as you have, but make sure you have the correct version (x86 vs x64).

Comment: Hi Jacob, do you know how do i force powershell to run in x86? i have powershell ISE also. the program seems working on x86 only.

Comment: You should have a shortcut named **Windows Powershell (x86)** in the Start menu, just hit the windows key and type **powershell**

Comment: But more importantly see the comment by @JacobH. You should install the 64bit redis if you are on a 64bit system.

Answer (score 0):

The OLEDB provider are 32-bit and 64-bit aware.

If only 32-bit provider is installed (when installed Office is 32-bit),
The script must be run using powershell (x86).
To do that, run this command:

```
& "$Env:WINDIR\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -File <script_file_path>
```

To list installed OLEDB, see [List all Ole DB Providers in Powershell](http://dbadailystuff.com/list-all-ole-db-providers-in-powershell).
The output may be different when run in Powershell (x64) and Powershell (x86).

```
function Get-OledbRegistered
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]])]
    param ()

    Process
    {
        $list = New-Object ([System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]])

        foreach ($provider in [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbEnumerator]::GetRootEnumerator())
        {
            $v = New-Object PSObject        
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $provider.FieldCount; $i++) 
            {
                Add-Member -in $v NoteProperty $provider.GetName($i) $provider.GetValue($i)
            }
            $list.Add($v)
        }
        return $list
    }
}

Get-OledbRegistered
```